# Why first argument of subroutine must be passed ByVal

Tags: excel, vba

I've following code:

```
Sub AddValidation()
   Dim ws, wsDefinitions As Worksheet
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TData")
   Set wsDefinitions = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Definitions")

   Call AddValidator(ws, wsDefinitions, "FaultType", FaultTypeColumn)
End Sub
```

And

```
Sub AddValidator(targetWs As Worksheet, definitionsWs As Worksheet, definitionTableName As String, targetColumnNumber)

    Dim definitionsRange As Range, targetRange As Range

    Set definitionsRange = definitionsWs.ListObjects(definitionTableName).ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
    Set targetRange = targetWs.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(targetColumnNumber).DataBodyRange

    With targetRange.Validation
        .Delete 'delete previous validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Formula1:="='" & definitionsWs.Name & "'!" & definitionsRange.Address
    End With

End Sub
```

During Compilation I get "ByRef argument type missmatch" for the first argument of AddValidator - "ws".
When I add ByVal to the definition:

```
Sub AddValidator(ByVal targetWs As Worksheet, definitionsWs As Worksheet, definitionTableName As String, targetColumnNumber)
```

Everything compiles fine. Two first arguments of "AddValidator" macro are Worksheet types but only first is required to be passed by Value.

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Try declaring both variable types: `Dim ws As Worksheet, wsDefinitions As Worksheet`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in declaration of variables.

```
Dim ws, wsDefinitions As Worksheet
```

Here `ws` gets declared as `variant` and not as `sheet` object and therefore Excel prompts you update the argument. If you fix this then Excel won't raise an error. Following sub will work without error.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    mySub ws1, ws2
End Sub
Sub mySub(targetWS As Worksheet, sourceWS As Worksheet)
    MsgBox targetWS.Name
    MsgBox sourceWS.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's the answer. I thought that Dim var1, var2 as Worksheet declares both variables as Worksheet, but apparently not. My fault and misunderstanding.